# How do you determine which Unicode characters are available on a particular terminal in Python 3?

Tags: python, unicode, printing, terminal, character

Currently, I have:

```
def allcharacters():
    def ch(u):
        try:
            c = chr(u)
            print(c if c else '', end='')
        except:
            c = ''
        return c
    return dict(filter(lambda en: en[1], enumerate(map(ch, range(0x110000)))))
```

The last line may be ugly (was uglier before revision), but my question centers on the call of the `print` function. This was the only way I found to force evaluation of `c`, which throws the exception needed for `allcharacters` to work by filtering out the null strings. I am interested in an alternative that has no side effects. Is there a way tell what characters are valid for a particular terminal without attempting to `print` them and without doing anything else that has a side effect?

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? As far as the programming language is concerned, all Unicode code points are valid, and can be sent to the terminal. Whether the terminal has installed fonts to actually display them is an OS/installation issue.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, by "valid," I mean that the terminal is able to produce an effect that is consistent with the Unicode description of the corresponding character. For most defined characters, this would be placing a graphical representation of the character at the cursor position.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a language thing, but an OS/Desktop/Font thing, and might not be possible on some platforms.